# Python string using date and time

Tags: python

This is a bit of a newbie question. I'm trying to change the format of a filename.

Currently it's in the format `sitename_products.xml`

```
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

...

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    file = open('%s_products.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')
    self.files[spider] = file
    self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(file)
    self.exporter.start_exporting()
```

How do I change it to be in the format `sitename_datetime.xml?`

This is what I have tried:

```
    file = open('%s_timestr.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')
```

Comment: Substitute `timestr` the same way that you substituted `spider.name`.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use str.format, also make sure you close files you open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform multiple `%` substitutions into a string.

```
file = open('%s_%s.xml' % (spider.name, timestr), 'w+b')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string concatenation as

```
 file = open(spider.name + '_' + timestr + '.xml', 'w+b')
```